# Привязка данных к TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml

Добрый день.

Имеется класс документов:

```
public class doc
{
    public string itemHeader = ""; //Наименование
    public Image itemImage //Изображение
    {
        get
        {
            return ;
        }
    }
    public int itemElementCount; //Кол-во вложенных элементов
    public List<doc> childs = new List<doc>(); //лист потомков элемента
}
```

Есть лист с документами, заполняющийся из БД:

```
List<doc> docItems = new List<doc>();
```

Необходимо заполнить TreeView данными из docItem. 
Какими хочется видеть TreeViewItem'ы:

[image: Примерный шаблон TreeViewItem'а]

1 - заголовок итема

2 - иконка итема

3 - кол-во вложеных документов

4 - потомки

Вот, что получилось наваять в xaml:

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1,1,1,1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding docItems}" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
```

ItemsSource="{Binding docItems}" - указал источником данных свой лист

Dictionary.xaml

```
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <!--Текст итема-->
                    <TextBlock x:Name="headerText" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding itemHeader}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <!--Иконка итема-->
                    <Image x:Name="itemImg" Source="{Binding itemImage}" Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <!--кол-во вложений в итеме-->
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding itemElementCount}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <!--кнопка с опциями для итема, типо контекстного меню-->
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="..." Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <!--чилдрены итема-->
                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="TreeViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TreeViewItemStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

Наваял, как я это себе логически представляю - создал treeView, указал источник данных, указал стиль для итемов, в стиле указал что из источника и куда брать, но не работает ничего - ошибок нет, как и TreeView. Без шаблонов и стилей из кода TreeView прекрасно заполняется, но хочется теперь научиться заполнять его с помощью шаблонов и стилей.

Покажите, пожалуйста, на конкретном примере, что я делаю не так, как нужно переписать, что нужно добавить/убрать в код/разметку?

P.S. Просьба сразу не минусить, wpf только начал изучать, а из-за огромного количества проумников-минусеров на форумах, кидающих пару ссылок со словами "держи, челядь", изучение не шибко сильно продвигается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделал через свой контрол - рекурсивно по данным запроса заполняю list и создаю контролы.

```
<UserControl>
<Grid x:Name="itemContent" DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="1">
     <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFF3E18D">            
         <Grid x:Name="customElement" Background="White">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="expandBtn" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0" Checked="toggleChecked" Unchecked="toggleChecked" IsChecked="False" ClickMode="Press">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=toggleImage}" />
                </ToggleButton>
                <TextBlock x:Name="headerText" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Path=itemHeader}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" MinWidth="75" FontSize="12" />
                <Image x:Name="itemImg" Source="{Binding Path=itemImage}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="itemElemCount" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=itemElemString}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="12"/>
                <Button Content="..." Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="-4" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold" Focusable="False"/>
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel x:Name="childGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,0,0" Height="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

class дополнил ссылкой на контрол:

```
public class path
{
     public string itemHeader //заголовок
     {
         get;


    set;
    }
    public itemTypes itemType = itemTypes.none; //значение из enum типов документов
    public BitmapImage itemImage
    {
        get
        {
            string imageName = "";
            switch (this.itemType)
            {
                case ... //в зависимости от типа выбираем нужную иконку
            }
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Resrs\Icons\" + imageName));
        }
    }
    public BitmapImage toggleImage
    {
        get
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Resrs\Icons\toggleItem.png"));
        }
    }
    public string itemElemString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemElementCount.ToString();
        }
    }
    public int itemElementCount = 0;
    public Guid itemGuid = Guid.Empty; //guid каталога из БД
    public Guid parentGuid = Guid.Empty; //guid родительского каталога
    private CustomTreeViewItem _tvi = null;
    public CustomTreeViewItem tvi
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tvi == null)
            {
                _tvi = new CustomTreeViewItem();
                _tvi.DataContext = this;
            }
            return _tvi;
        }
    }
    public List<path> childs = new List<path>();
}
```